# Biharmonic operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, harmonic-functions

Consider the problem:

$$ \Delta^2 u = f$$

on the square domain $U=(0,1)\times(0,1)$ with boundary conditions:

$$ u(x,y)=\Delta u(x,y) = 0$$

for $(x,y) \in \partial U.$

I try to solve it with the hint that i should use separation of variables but i can not do it.
I write $u(x,y) = X(x) \cdot Y(y)$ and i plug this in the equation $ \Delta^2 u = \lambda u$ to get 
$$ X^{(4)} +2X^{(2)}Y^{(2)}+Y^{(4)} = \lambda XY$$ and here i am stuck.
Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Let's write $v=\Delta u$. The equation for $v$ is $\Delta v=f$ with boundary condition $v=0$. Presumably you know how to "solve" that (whatever "solve" means here, when $f$ is not given). Then $\Delta u=v$ is another problem of the same kind.

Comment: Where did you got this problem? What kind of funtion is $f$? What do you mean by solve it? Looks like you want to find a explicitly function and this is not a easy task to do (the most of times it is impossible).

Comment: For future reference, the type of boundary condition you have given here, where you leave the first derivative free, is known as Navier boundary conditions, and the general way to solve equations with such conditions is to turn it into an elliptic system, just as 5pm suggested.

Comment: @Tomás : It is fairly difficult to solve - I suspect all they want is the usual representation in terms of the Fourier coefficients of $f$.